# Can someone explain to me how this "Dictionary" version of Fibonacci sequence works?

Tags: python, dictionary, fibonacci

```
    known = {0:0, 1:1}

def fibonacci(n):
    if n in known:
        return known[n]
    result = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    known[n] = result
    return result

print(fibonacci(4))
```

So how does this dictionary(memorized version) of fib. sequence works? I thought #whenever we call a new parameter (not called before) it will take some time to compute, just like recursion version do. But it just outputs result immediately. So does it mean all fibo. results were stored in python program itself, so it computes very fast just because we used dict. and called it?

Comment: The `known` dictionary caches the result of previous computations. This technique is usually called "memoization".

Comment: Well, it calculates fibonacci numbers recursively, and saves the result for each input in a dict, and uses that already computed result from the dict if available…?!

Comment: Try adding a `print(f"Looking up fib({n}) in cache. Found value {known[n]}.")` statement before `return known[n]` to see it in action.

Comment: Looking up fib(1) in cache. Found value 1.
Looking up fib(0) in cache. Found value 0.
Looking up fib(1) in cache. Found value 1.
Looking up fib(2) in cache. Found value 1.
3

Comment: Oh that's interesting...it's like giving me some history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an implementation of [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). The dictionary will register any computed outcome so to avoid that the same work has to be done again when the function is called with the same argument.

Without memoization, the function would have looked like this:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    result = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    return result
```

Then the call `fibonacci(5)` would result in these calls to the function:

```
fibonacci(5)
    fibonacci(4)
        fibonacci(3)
            fibonacci(2)
                fibonacci(1)
                   return 1
            fibonacci(1)
                return 1
        fibonacci(2)
            fibonacci(1)
                return 1
            fibonacci(0)
                return 0
    fibonacci(3)
        fibonacci(2)
            fibonacci(1)
               return 1
        fibonacci(1)
            return 1
    fibonacci(2)
        fibonacci(1)
            return 1
        fibonacci(0)
            return 0
```

Note how (for example) `fibonacci(3)` is called twice and for the second of those two calls all the recursive calls are made again. In total `fibonacci(2)` is recalculated four times. By using the dictionary version, the recursion tree will not do that double work:

```
fibonacci(5)
    fibonacci(4)
        fibonacci(3)
            fibonacci(2)
                fibonacci(1)
                   return 1  # from dictionary
            fibonacci(1)
                return 1  # from dictionary
        fibonacci(2)
            return 1  # from dictionary
    fibonacci(3)
        return 2  # from dictionary
```

And after calling `fibonacci(5)` the dictionary will look like this:

```
{
    0: 0,
    1: 1,
    2: 1,
    3: 2,
    4: 3,
    5: 5
}
```

So if later on you call `fibonacci(6)`, the recursion tree will not have to go that deep:

```
fibonacci(6)
    fibonacci(5)
       return 5  # from dictionary
    fibonacci(4)
       return 3  # from dictionary
```

...and the result will have been added to the dictionary... etc.